# Can this expression be calculated symbolically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I want to do definite integration of the following expression

```
expr=(4*θ*Sqrt[1/(1 + (4*Cos[θ])/169)]*Cos[θ]*
   Sqrt[(-4*Sqrt[1/(1 + (4*Cos[θ])/169)]*Sin[θ] + 
       (8/169)*(1/(1 + (4*Cos[θ])/169))^(3/2)*Cos[θ]*Sin[θ])^2 + 
     (4*Sqrt[1/(1 + (4*Cos[θ])/169)]*Cos[θ] + 
       (8/169)*(1/(1 + (4*Cos[θ])/169))^(3/2)*Sin[θ]^2)^2])/
  (9/4 + (16*Cos[θ]^2)/(1 + (4*Cos[θ])/169) + 
    (16*Sin[θ]^2)/(1 + (4*Cos[θ])/169))^(3/2)
```

But when I do `Integrate[expr,{θ,0,2*Pi}]` it just goes on and on and dont stop in 5 mins.  The `expr` is smooth on the whole interval of integration. Here is the plot.

```
Plot[expr, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

Please tell me what could be the reason of such behavior of Mathematica? How do I properly integrate this expression? Maybe the only way is to do `NIntegrate[]`? And how one knows if the expression can be integrated symbolically?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this would have a simple symbolic result.  Wouldn't a numerical one do?

Comment: @Szabolcs in Mapple it gives the symbolic result very fast. So there should be one. Maybe I need to use some options in `Integrate[]` function?`NIntegrate[]` gives the expected result, but I need the symbolic one.

Comment: @Szabolcs sry, my bad. Maple doesnt give the symbolic result. Maybe u are right. I will edit my question now.

Comment: I was just about to say, I've tried running the integration on python, and it doesn't do any better than Mathematica.

Comment: @Feyre ty, I think it can be calculated only numerically.

Comment: Used the Rubi 4.9 package, resulted in a different Integration it could not solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
NIntegrate[expr,{\[Theta],0,2*Pi}]// Timing
```

> {0.008, 0.0151049}

When you integrating it within a limit, it will always give you a number, not a function. Now, say you are interested in finding the integration as a function of the upper limit. In that case you can get an `InterpolatingFunction` which you can use in any further calculation.

```
data = Table[{x, NIntegrate[expr, {\[Theta], 0, x}]}, {x, 0., 4 Pi, Pi/50.}];
f[x_] = Interpolation[data][x]; 

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Prolog -> Point[data]]
```

[image]

So your answer is `f[x]`. You can try to fit it with any trial function. Probably it is possible to get an analytic answer with proper `Assumption`, but I am not very sure about that. So wait for a better answer.

Comment: Why it is a list and not one number?

Comment: First one is the time and second is the result

Comment: @Sumit, you forgot the `Timing` ;)

Comment: @Sumit ok, I know that this can be calculated with `NIntegrate[]`. Can it be calculated symbolically?

Comment: @Sumit, I need the `expr` to be integrate over `\[Theta]` not x

Comment: sorry I just saw that. There are too many nb open in my desktop